# Docky shows default launcher icon on ubuntu

Tags: linux, gnome, docky

I am using docky on Ubuntu. I want to have a launcher for intellij in my docky bar, but I have an issue.

No matter which method for adding the launcher to the dock I use, the intellij icon specified in my `.desktop` won't display. Instead I get the lame spring board launcher icon. Once I launch intellij it creates another icon on docky. So now I have intellij's correct icon and the spring board launcher icon. Once I close intellij we are back to just the spring board again.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

I should also note that "idea" launches a shell script if that matters

**Desktop file**

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                                                                               
Categories=GNOME;Development;                                                                                                                 
Name=Intellij IDE                                                                                                                             
Comment=Idea IntelliJ IDE                                                                                                                     
Exec=idea                                                                                                                                     
Hidden=false                                                                                                                                  
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher                                                                                                                     
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/idea.png                                                                                                    
Name=Intellij IDE                                                                                                                             
Name[en_US]=Intellij IDE                                                                                                                      
Terminal=false                                                                                                                                
Type=Application                                                                                                                              
Version=1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36434/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-icons-for-launched-java-programs-in-the-launcher/40327#40327